# How to pass JSON string or object from dojo xhr post call to POST method implemented in Java

Tags: java, ajax, json, rest, dojo

I am trying to pass JSON string using javascript (dojo xhr) to a POST method implemented using Apache Wink library.

Below is my javascript code using dojo/_base/xhr:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({"id" : "1", "status" : "Red", "title" : "Incident 1"});

xhr.post
(
    {
       headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
       },
       handleAs : "json",
       content : data,
       load : function(data, ioArgs)
       {
           alert(data);
       },
       error : function(error, ioArgs)
       {
           alert(error);                            
       }
   }
);
```

Below is my POST method code in Java:-

```
@POST
@Path("saveIncidents")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void saveIncidents(String incidentData) 
{ 
    try {
         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(incidentData);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
```

However, I get exception as:

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1
```

Below is what I get in String variable 'incidentData':

```
0=%7B&1=%22&2=i&3=d&4=%22&5=%3A&6=%22&7=1&8=%22&9=%2C&10=%22&11=i&12=n&13=c&14=i&15=d&16=e&17=n&18=t&19=S&20=t&21=a&22=t&23=u&24=s&25=%22&26=%3A&27=%22&28=R&29=e&30=d&31=%22&32=%2C&33=%22&34=i&35=n&36=c&37=i&38=d&39=e&40=n&41=t&42=T&43=i&44=t&45=l&46=e&47=%22&48=%3A&49=%22&50=I&51=n&52=c&53=i&54=d&55=e&56=n&57=t&58=%20&59=1&60=%22&61=%7D
```

Does anyone know how to go about it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of how stringify is used?  Here is one example which I got from msdn.

```
var contact = new Object(); 
contact.firstname = "Jesper";
contact.surname = "Aaberg";
contact.phone = ["555-0100", "555-0120"];

var jsonText = JSON.stringify(contact);
document.write(jsonText);
```

Comment: {"id" : "1", "incidentStatus" : "Red", "incidentTitle" : "Incident 1"} is valid JSON object.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836459(v=vs.94).aspx as per this it says "stringify" converts javascript object to JSON String.  Why are you passing JSON String to stringify?

Comment: It is JSON object not JSON string. BTW I also tried - var obj = new Object();
         obj.id = "1";
         obj.incidentStatus = "Red";
         obj.incidentTitle = "Incident 1";   var data = JSON.stringify(obj);   Same problem.

Comment: are you sure you have to pass in content key?  Is there data key?  I think you have to pass like  --  postData: dojo.toJson({key1:"value1",key2:{key3:"value2"}}),

Comment: Saw the documentation here http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html.  It says in options you have data tag.  content option is not there.  Please check.

Comment: I am using dojo/_base/xhr not dojo/request/xhr.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have resolved it like this -

```
@POST
@Path("saveIncidents")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void saveIncidents(String encodedIncidentData) {

    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    String incidentData = "";
    StringTokenizer mainTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(encodedIncidentData, "&");

    while(mainTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        String token = mainTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
        StringTokenizer innerTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(token, "=");

        String character = null;
        while(innerTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
            character = innerTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
        }

        if(character.equals("%2C")){
            character = ",";
        }
        else if(character.equals("%22")){
            character = "\"";
        }
        else if(character.equals("%7B")){
            character = "{";
        }
        else if(character.equals("%7D")){
            character = "}";
        }
        else if(character.equals("%3A")){
            character = ":";
        }
        else if(character.equals("%5D")){
            character = "]";
        }
        else if(character.equals("%5B")){
            character = "[";
        }
        else if(character.equals("%20")){
            character = " ";
        }

        incidentData += character;

    }

    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(incidentData);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Still, please let me know if any efficient solution is there. Thanks.